# Cleanup Windows on startup or shutdown

Tags: windows, batch, cleaning, windows-task-scheduler, disk-cleanup

**My Environment**

Multiple VMs all comprising of Various versions of Windows which is power on/off as needed

i like to cleanup my `%temp%` and other places on reboot so as to save space and also speed up the OS

**My Current Technique**

I used a batch file that triggers "At log on of any User"

***Batch File Contents***

```
cleanmgr /d C: /sagerun:900  // this one has everything checked on Disk Cleanup
cd %temp%
for /d %%D in (*) do rd /s /q "%%D"
del /f /q *
```

Questions:

1. Any alternatives to cleanmgr to clean up my OS on reboot which is faster
2. My section around clean `%temp%` gives access denied when launching at logon, is there a way to run this before login when no files from `%temp%` are in use
3. What else can be cleaned without harming Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bat files:**

You can use the below command to delete temp files using below command:

`cd C:\Users\mn\AppData\Local\Temp
echo y | del *
cd C:\Windows\Temp
echo y | del *
exit`

Change the user name to yours and save as bat file.

**Procedure:**

You can create a local computer policy on Windows. See the TechNet at [Click](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd630947)

1) Run gpedit.msc to open the Group Policy Editor,

2) Navigate to Computer Configuration | Windows Settings | Scripts (Startup/Shutdown).

[image]